# Do the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines apply to secondary states of links/buttons?

Tags: hover, focus, accessibility, contrast, wcag2.0

Is it good enough that all text+background combinations pass the [level AA contrast guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#visual-audio-contrast) in their default states (i.e. contrast ratio of 4.5:1)?

We have some links and buttons where the background changes opacity on hover/focus and this then doesn't pass the contrast check. Can anyone confirm if that's a problem or if it's acceptable so long as the default state passes?

Comment: This question seems either too broad or to be opinion based and so may be off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's a major problem.**

If WCAG requires you to have a contrast of 4.5:1 between background and text color, it obviously applies to focused links which are the very first thing a user will want to read when tabbing around a web page.

Comment: That's what I figured but I was just wondering if there was some more specific guidance out there as the official guidelines make no mention of this kind of thing. Do you happen to know of any user testing or other source that could be used as a reference for this?

Comment: Adam is correct, the only state that is excluded is the disabled state, you can infer by omission that all other states are included